# How to delete a single cell?

Tags: r

So, I am trying to delete a single cell from my data. The problem is that a normal function doesn't work:

```
data[-1,]
data[-1,-1]
data$x = NULL
```

etc

So that's how my main code looks like:

```
data_rd <- data_rd[-1,]  ## I could delete one row but can't the next one. 

## Create an empty matrix
name_cols <- paste0("F", rep(1:20, each = 4), "_", 1:4)
name_columns <- c("Description", name_cols)

mat_master_EOD <- matrix(0, nrow = length(data_rd[,1]),ncol = 81)
colnames(mat_master_EOD) <- name_columns
rownames(mat_master_EOD) <- data_rd[,1]
```

The cell which I want to delete:
http://imageshack.com/a/img32/6227/hy0s.jpg

I used `rbind.fill`function to group some of data files, that might be the reason why I am not able to remove this cell.

EDIT:
That's only what I can do for you:

```
dput(data_rd[1:3, 1:3])
structure(list(X = c("Accession", "ZZ_FGCZCont0025", "ZZ_FGCZCont0099"
), X.1 = structure(c(29L, 22L, 20L), .Label = c("", "1", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", 
"21", "23", "25", "27", "28", "29", "3", "34", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "Peptide count", "22", "24", "26", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "35", "36", "37", "40", "41", "45", "46", "50", "55", 
"63", "73", "38", "48", "56", "68", "82", "39", "42", "43", "44", 
"58", "67", "76", "90", "59", "49", "54", "71", "65", "51", "53", 
"57", "61", "64", "74", "75", "47", "52", "60", "72", "69", "70", 
"62"), class = "factor"), X.2 = structure(c(23L, 9L, 15L), .Label = c("", 
"0", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "2", "28", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Peptides used for quantitation", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "29", "30", "33", 
"37", "39", "41", "45", "46", "49", "32", "34", "35", "36", "44", 
"68", "40", "43", "47", "66", "88", "42", "59", "58", "52", "71", 
"31", "38", "51", "48", "50", "62"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
"X.1", "X.2"), row.names = 2:4, class = "data.frame")
```

And for the new created matrix:

```
> dput(mat_master_EOD[1:10, 1:10])
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(c("Accession", "ZZ_FGCZCont0025", "ZZ_FGCZCont0099", 
"ZZ_FGCZCont0126", "ZZ_FGCZCont0146", "AT1G19570", "ZZ_FGCZCont0158", 
"AT5G38480", "ZZ_FGCZCont0050", "AT1G07370"), c("Description", 
"F1_1", "F1_2", "F1_3", "F1_4", "F2_1", "F2_2", "F2_3", "F2_4", 
"F3_1")))
```

Comment: can you `dput(data[1:10, 1:10])`?

Comment: Done. I would like to have easy access to first column by setting the name of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the cell"? You can never delete a cell in a matrix, only remove its contents.

Comment: Hmm... I just want to put the "Accession" to the first row in the first column. Is there any way to do it ? Should I convert my data_rd to something and then delete the proper cell and after that create my matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reaching here, but is this is what you're trying to get:

```
        Accession Peptide count Peptides used for quantitation
3 ZZ_FGCZCont0025            34                             15
4 ZZ_FGCZCont0099            29                             28
```

If so, you can do this:

```
setNames(data_rd[-1,], sapply(data_rd[1, ], as.character))
```

Note that your `Peptide...` columns are factors, which is terribly confusing for numeric columns.  You should consider re-importing the data using something like `read.csv(file="blahblah", header=TRUE)` which I think will resolve most your problems from the get go.

Comment: After creating a matrix it still gives me this empty cell.. I will try to play with it tomorrow coz I have to leave now.

Comment: I used those functions to load a files: tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list_of_data = lapply(tbl, read.csv)